# Box api for multiple files download

Tags: box-api, box

I want to download multiple files in zip format from my BOX account by BOX API. Is it possible? Or should we download multiple file calling the api multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

It's currently not possible to download a folder as a Zip through the Box API.

To download all the files in a folder, you would first have to get a list of the files in a folder by calling the [Get Folder's Items endpoint](https://docs.box.com/reference#get-a-folders-items). Then you would have to call the [Download File endpoint](https://docs.box.com/reference#download-a-file) for each of the files.